# jquery validation plugin - not validating on submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've got a form with several fields, some of which I'd like to have validated on keyup and on submit. I am calling jquery 1.9.1  then the plugin (1.11.1), then an external file with my js. I see via Firebug they are all loading.  If I use the code below, it does not validate at all - the form submits, and I get mysql errors because I don't have fields filled out.  Here is the js code:

```
    $("#untForm").validate({
     onfocusout: true,
    rules: {
        attachment: {
            required: "false",
            accept: "jp?g,png,gif,txt"
        },
        recipient: {
            required: "true"
        },
        messageInput: { 
            required: "true"
        },
        cc_email: {
            email: "true"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        attachment: {
            accept: "Only image type jpg/png/jpeg/gif and .txt are allowed"
        },
        recipient: {
            required: "Please enter a recipient"
        },
        messageInput: {
             required: "Please enter a message"
        },
        cc_email: {
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    },
    });
```

If I add this piece of code in the beginning:

```
$("#untForm").submit(function() {
```

it validates on submit - all but the cc_email field. This never gets validated. 
All my form fields have a name attribute.  This seems like I must be missing something simple, but I've spent hours looking at this, and other Q&A on this form. Can anyone see what I'm dong wrong?

Part of the html markup:

```
<form action=""  id="untForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="general" method="post" >
    <h1>Send a Message</h1>
    <hr color="#ff6C00" width="100%"><br>
    <label for="recipient">To: <span>(required)</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="recipient"  id="recipient" class="form-input" "required" />
<label for="attachment">Attachment: <span>(optional)</span></label>
<img src="images/paperclip.png" width="32px"><input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" /></img>
                                                   <label for="cc_email">Cc: <span>(optional)</span></label>
   <input type="text" name="cc_email" id="cc_email" class="form-input" />
                                                       <textarea id="messageInput" class="form-input" name="messageInput" cols="30" rows="30" required></textarea>

    <input class="form-btn" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

Comment: So show us the HTML markup.

Comment: edited to include HTML markup

Comment: Your `cc_email` field is validating perfectly fine, but since you're only specifying the `email` rule then the user is also allowed to leave it blank.  If you want it mandatory, then you also need to set the `required` rule.

Comment: Is your jQuery enclosed within a DOM ready handler?  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems...

1. *"If I add this piece of code in the beginning:"* `$("#untForm").submit(function() {`

**You absolutely do not need to add a submit handler**.  The plugin already captures the click of the submit button and handles everything *automatically*.

2. Your code must be enclosed within a DOM ready handler to ensure the HTML markup for the form exists when you call the `.validate()` method.  (This omission explains why nothing was working until you enclosed it within a `submit()` handler.)
3. The `onfocusout` option is *activated* by default.  [As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout), setting it to `true` *"is not a valid value"*.  (Setting it to `true` can break things.)  If you want this option, you must leave out `onfocusout: true` because it's already the default.
4. The rules with boolean parameters, such as `required`, do not get quotation marks around the `true` parameter.

   ```
   required: true
   ```
5. Not sure why you have `required: false` on the `attachment` field.  If you don't specify the `required` rule, then the field is not required (it's optional).  There's no purpose in setting it to `false` when leaving it out achieves the same.
6. Based on your parameters of `"jp?g,png,gif,txt"`, I'm not sure you intended to use [the `accept` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/), which is for MIME Types.  Those look like file extensions, and in that case, you should be using [the `extension` rule](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/) instead.  If that's the case, they need to be separated with a `|` character.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/
7. When you use the `accept` or `extension` rules, you must include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js), just in case you haven't.
8. Not sure what you meant by "not validated" on the `cc_email` field.  You've only defined the `email` rule so when you enter an non-email address, it will give you an error.  However, you did not specify the `required` rule so this field will be optional.  If you want it mandatory, then add `required`.

   ```
   cc_email: {
       required: true,
       email: true
   }
   ```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ca2Rd/**

DEMO with your markup:  http://jsfiddle.net/mECS9/

---

**HTML markup issues.**

1. `<img>` elements are not containers, do not have a closing tag, and you cannot put other elements inside of them.  They are stand-alone and self-closing, similar to a `<br />` tag.

NOT valid:  `<img> ... </img>`

NOT valid:  `<img></img>`

Valid: `<img />`

Valid: `<img>`

2. You do not need the `required` attribute inside of the `<textarea>` tag since you've already defined the `required` rule inside of your `.validate()` method.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"... and I get mysql errors because I don't have fields filled out ..."*

This is a very serious problem.  Client-side validation by JavaScript or jQuery, can routinely be bypassed, broken or disabled.  Therefore, you should **NEVER** rely on any client-side code to protect your database from errors.

You absolutely must have code on your server-side that also validates the incoming data and therefore will always protect your database from errors, even when the client-side validation fails in any fashion.

- **Client-side validation** is for avoiding frequent page reloads, for a more pleasant GUI and user experience, etc.
- **Server-side validation** is for protecting your database whenever client-side validation fails.

***You should have both, but absolutely do not go without "server-side" validation.***  In other words, client-side validation is only an *enhancement* to server-side validation, ***never*** a replacement.

Comment: That is great - thank you so much.  I absolutely have server-side validation, was just pointing out that the validation plugin was not working well.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @DevangHingu, if you have a new question, then post it as a new question, not a comment.   However, in this case, there are already SO questions that answer it, so please do a search first.  You'll need to capture the click event and programmatically trigger validation.

Answer (score -1):

I was tearing my hair out for over an hour with a similar issue (the email field was not being validated). I figured there must be something wrong with my HTML markup and upon examining the demos, found that they were using an input type="email" to capture the input. I was using a regular text input. Making the change solved my problem.